# How can I increase my early heroic tier Wizard's attack roll?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization

can you provide some suggestions on how to increase my level 2 Wizard enchanter's attack rolls?  FYI my Int is 19 and I've already taken the staff expertise Feat at level one.  At level two I chose the improved initiative feat although I can still switch it out if need be.

Currently my attack roll is +6 vs will with most of my enchantment powers (+7 with my staff implement equipped).  +7 doesn't seem like very much..  how can I improve that beyond getting combat advantage in battle?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is an [optimisation handbook for wizards](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/28817645/Archmages_Ascension_-_The_Wizards_Handbook) that might be of interest to you Bruce.

Comment: Average monster non AC defences are 12+yourleve, 12+2 = 14 - 6 - 1(for ties) = 7 that means you're hitting 65% of the time. That's all right. It can be better, but you're operating under some heavy feat constraints at this point.

Comment: If however your difficulty is that the Dice Gods are against you, it helps to bear in mind that wizards have a lot of options for spells that still do something useful on a miss.

Answer (score 8):

Player's Handbook 3 introduced superior implements. You could take the `Superior Implement Proficiency` feat and start using an accurate staff, which gives an additional +1 attack (accurate is part of the base item; an accurate staff can have the same enchantments a regular staff can).

Once you have that and an Expertise feat, though, there aren't very many other ways to increase your attack until you hit paragon tier at level 11. That shouldn't be too much of a problem, though; +7 is actually fine for implement attacks at level 2. Weapon-users have higher attack bonuses because AC is higher than fort/refl/will.

Comment: wouldn't hurt to mention that a good rule of thumb is to assume that your enemy's AC is 14+ your level and NADs are 12+your level. That gives you a baseline to determine your odds to hit.